# How to get the lists' length in one column in dataframe spark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a df whose 'products' column are lists like below:

```
+----------+---------+--------------------+
|member_srl|click_day|            products|
+----------+---------+--------------------+
|        12| 20161223|  [2407, 5400021771]|
|        12| 20161226|        [7320, 2407]|
|        12| 20170104|              [2407]|
|        12| 20170106|              [2407]|
|        27| 20170104|        [2405, 2407]|
|        28| 20161212|              [2407]|
|        28| 20161213|      [2407, 100093]|
|        28| 20161215|           [1956119]|
|        28| 20161219|      [2407, 100093]|
|        28| 20161229|           [7905970]|
|       124| 20161011|        [5400021771]|
|      6963| 20160101|         [103825645]|
|      6963| 20160104|[3000014912, 6626...|
|      6963| 20160111|[99643224, 106032...|
```

How to add a new column `product_cnt` which are the length of `products` list? And how to filter df to get specified rows with condition of given products length ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 42):

Pyspark has a built-in function to achieve exactly what you want called `size`. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size .
To add it as column, you can simply call it during your select statement.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import size

countdf = df.select('*',size('products').alias('product_cnt'))
```

Filtering works exactly as @titiro89 described. Furthermore, you can use the `size` function in the filter. This will allow you to bypass adding the extra column (if you wish to do so) in the following way.

```
filterdf = df.filter(size('products')==given_products_length)
```

Comment: You can find the latest docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.size.html?highlight=size#pyspark-sql-functions-size). (Link in the answer is broken, @DavidWayne.)

Answer (score 14):

**First question**:

> How to add a new column product_cnt which are the length of products list?

```
>>> a = [(12,20161223, [2407,5400021771]),(12,20161226,[7320,2407])]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(a,
["member_srl","click_day","products"])
>>> df.show()
+----------+---------+------------------+
|member_srl|click_day|          products|
+----------+---------+------------------+
|        12| 20161223|[2407, 5400021771]|
|        12| 20161226|[7320, 2407, 4344]|
+----------+---------+------------------+
```

You can find a similar example [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=withcolumn#pyspark.sql.functions.udf)

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

>>> slen = udf(lambda s: len(s), IntegerType())

>>> df2 = df.withColumn("product_cnt", slen(df.products))
>>> df2.show()
+----------+---------+------------------+-----------+
|member_srl|click_day|          products|product_cnt|
+----------+---------+------------------+-----------+
|        12| 20161223|[2407, 5400021771]|          2|
|        12| 20161226|[7320, 2407, 4344]|          3|
+----------+---------+------------------+-----------+
```

**Second question**:

> And how to filter df to get specified rows with condition of given products length ?

You can use *filter* function [docs here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=filter#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter)

```
>>> givenLength = 2
>>> df3 = df2.filter(df2.product_cnt==givenLength)
>>> df3.show()
+----------+---------+------------------+-----------+
|member_srl|click_day|          products|product_cnt|
+----------+---------+------------------+-----------+
|        12| 20161223|[2407, 5400021771]|          2|
+----------+---------+------------------+-----------+
```